# Pinia not yet instanciated, wrong order of JavaScript file execution in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, pinia

I'm making a Vue.js application with Vite, and I have a Pinia store which I would like to watch. The `store .js` file looks like this:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

const useStore = defineStore('store', {
  state: () => ({
    currentLayout: {},
    currentPuzzle: {},
    difficulty: 2,
    solvedPuzzles: new Set(),
  }),
  actions: {
    setLayout(layout) {
      this.currentLayout = layout;
    },
    setPuzzle(puzzle) {
      this.currentPuzzle = puzzle;
    }
  }
});

export default useStore;
```

To watch it, I tried doing the following right before the export statement:

```js
const store = useStore();
... // some vue.js watching logic
```

But as soon as I call `useStore` here, I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
```

Then, I observed through console.logs that the `main.js` file is actually executed after `store.js` so Pinia hasn't been instanciated yet. What is the main way to do something like this ? And what specifies the order of execution of these JavaScript files in a Vue.js application ?
I am using Vue v3.3.4, Vite v4.3.9 and Pinia v2.1.4 (should just be the latest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main.js you need to import the methods to instantiate pinia:

```
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from 'pinia';
```

then :

```
const pinia = createPinia();

setActivePinia(pinia);
app.use(pinia);
```

[Instantiate Pinia out of components](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html#single-page-applications)

Also I recommend you using the composition syntax for stores, therefore it allows you to make watchers easily.

[Setup store](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#setup-stores)

You can even use the subscribe method to watch directly your Pinia state:

[Pinia subscribe](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#subscribing-to-the-state)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did create the Pinia instance in `main.js` however I didn't call `setActivePinia(pinia)`. I just tried and it doesn't make a difference, calls to `useStore` right after the export still throw an error. So I guess I'll switch to the composition syntax, that should work